# Uniform convergence of a series with sin

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition, cauchy-sequences

Uniform convergence. I need to use the definition or the Cauchy criterion. The series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\sin\dfrac{1}{1+nx}\right)^2.$$

Also I need to find the radius of convergence of the series. 
Might you help me with that?

Comment: Actually, I tried so much times to solve the problem. And I never could find the answer.

Comment: Can you add some details about your attempt?

Comment: @RRL Yes. (Sin(1+nx))^2 <= 1/(1+nx)^2. Using the Cauchy criterion: |1/(1+(n+1)x) + ... + 1/(1+(n+p)x)^2| <= p/(1+(n+1)x)^2 <= ? Here I can reduce the fractional denominator, but what to do with P?

Comment: @user726925 why are you doing $\sin(1+nx)^2 \leq \frac{1}{(1+nx)^2}$? Do you mean $\sin(\frac{1}{1+nx})^2 \leq \frac{1}{(1+nx)^2}$?

Comment: @RRL Another one: the series with sin is equal 1/2 - 1/2*cos(2/(1+nx)) by the degree reduction formula. Then I use Cauchy criterion and there is a problem: I can't valuate cos. It can take any value. But to "delete" P I need to use cos in my valuation.

Comment: What about: $\sin(\frac{1}{1+nx})^2 < \frac{1}{(1+nx)^2}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+nx)^2} < \infty \ \forall x \neq 0$$ and therefore $$| \frac{1}{(1+(n+1)x)^2} + \frac{1}{(1+(n+2)x)^2} + \dots \frac{1}{(1+(n+p)x)^2}| < \epsilon$$ for large enough n

Comment: @GhostAmarth yes, just a mistake

Comment: @GhostAmarth actually, I didn't say that 0 < x < infinity. But anyway, I need to find N dependent on X. I need to get *something with n and constants* <= epsilon.

Comment: @user726925 yes that $0 < x < \infty$ was my mistake. I already fixed it in my comment.

Comment: @GhostAmarth to prove that the series converges uniformly I need to find the N dependent on X.

Comment: @user726925: Add some of your work to the original question.  First explain where the series converges pointwise. What happens if $x = 0$. I can help you with the uniform convergence part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have non-uniform convergence on a set $S$ where $0$ is a limit point. For example, consider  $S = (0,\infty)$.  Using the inequality $2x/\pi \leqslant \sin x$ for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \pi/2$. and $1/(1+nx) \leqslant 1$ we have

$$\frac{4}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{(1+nx)^2} \leqslant \sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{1+nx} \right) ,$$

and

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{1+kx}\right) \geqslant  n \cdot \sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{1+2nx}\right) \geqslant n \cdot \frac{4}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{(1+2nx)^2}$$

With $x = 1/n$ we see that

$$\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{1+kx}\right) \geqslant \frac{4n}{\pi^2(1 + 2n \cdot \frac{1}{n})}= \frac{4n}{3\pi^2}$$

Since the RHS does not converge to $0$ -- in fact, it diverges to $+\infty$ -- as $n \to \infty$, it follows that the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence is violated.

On the other hand, can you show that the convergence is uniform for $x \in [\delta, \infty)$ when $\delta > 0$?  Also what happens if $x < 0$?

Comment: Wow. You showed me a way that I have not tried. I will think about this one

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: +1...  For $x>0$ let $F_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\sin^2((nx+1)^{-1}$ and $F(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}F_n(x).$... If $F_n$ converged uniformly to $F$ on $\Bbb R^+$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{x>0}|F_n(x)-F_{n+1}(x)|\le$ $\le  \lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{x>0}|F_n(x)-F(x)|+|F(x)-F_{n+1}(x)|=0$.... BUT  with $x_n=(n+1)^{-1}(4/\pi -1)$ we have $\sup_{x>0}|F_{n+1}(x)-F_n(x)|\ge$ $ |F_{n+1}(x_n)-F(x_n)| =$ $\sin^2(((n+1)x_n+1)^{-1})=$ $\sin^2(\pi/4)=$ $1/4.$